# ASPxComboBox unable to change column name using new ListBoxColumn()

Tags: c#, asp.net, devexpress

When I try to change the column header for a dropdown list of type ASPxComboBox get an error saying "A field with the name '' was not found on the selected data source."
Eg:
The column header is set to Contact Name I need to change it.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When working with DevExpress columns, the `FieldName` is used to determine which property on the underlying datasource is used for that column. If no `Caption` is provided, it will parse the name of the property to use as the column header. Instead, try setting the `Caption` property in the ASP.NET client side code.